# what's the best webdriver

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, watin

I'm developing automated tests for a web application (base on MVC)
I'd like to know what is the best webdriver between Selenium and [Coypu](https://github.com/adiel/Coypu) ? any others?

Comment: Oh for a .Net based browser that would publish events for relevant actions (DOM Load/ContentLoad, XHR begin /end etc) then we'd have more control and could act/test on actual browser activity rather than anticipated (via sleeps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://watin.org/ is available. 
I think there's a Load/Web test kit in Visual Studio too.

Coypu - https://github.com/ITV/Coypu - is excellent and more tolerant around XmlHttpResponses.
Coypu is a wrapper around Selenium.
It fixes the fragile nature of Selenium (e.g. WebDriverException). Coypu wraps, listens and waits for responses.

I've found Coypu to be a great head start and muchbetter than raw Selenium.

Comment: Microsoft seems to support SpecFlow and WatiN 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490346.aspx
+1 anyway for the quick answer